# Cover letter for job advertised by recruiter

Tags: recruitment, cover-letter

For positions advertised by recruiters, the details tend to be vague. Is it a good idea to ask a recruiter for more information about a position before replying so that I can write a more targeted cover letter, or should I just write a cover letter based on the information I've got?

Comment: Who are you writing a cover-letter for? Usually, if you're going through an agent, he does all the work of introducing you and selling you as worth-an-interview.

Comment: @pdr: Saw a recruiter advertising on seek. I sent him an email ('cover letter') with my resume attached

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never write a general cover letter. It is always good to ask for more information about the position - it shows genuine interest in the job and it helps both sides to find out if there is a match.

Asking a recruiter about the job is good since he will try to sell the job and you'll have a perfect starting point for the cover letter.